# CSS Background url image looks blurry in bigger resolution but looks sharp in smaller screen resolution

Tags: css

I am having a issue on blurry background url image in css for bigger screen resolution 1920. I'm using a 54px X 54px png icon for quick menu on website. The icon image looks blurry in 1920 but when i scale down the screen resolution to 1280x720, the icon image looks sharp. I'm using background-size to resize it to 25px. is there other solution i can use to resize the icon image so that it looks sharp across the different resolution or should I use a bigger icon image like 512px?

This is the code im using:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a id="icon">click here</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#icon {
  line-height: 26px;
  display: block;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1eGJUC18ZwUK_YXBqQ6bZMQnGxl1atWcj") 
  left center no-repeat;
  background-size:25px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kimberleeho/pen/XWjZXVm

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please put some sort of a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert an image in a different resolution without it becoming blurred, then you must choose an image in SVG format and not PNG or JPG. With Inkscape (https://inkscape.org/) you can even create your own image in SVG format.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. i've tried with svg format, its resizing correctly based on resolution. its kind of impossible to use .png and .jpg seamlessly unless we create different sizes of image and work with media queries.

Answer (score 1):

It is blurry because the icon size 25 is not a divider of actual image size 54. You should use 50px or 100px image.

I have to add: for those small icons it is always best to use a SVG image instead, as [this one](https://iconmonstr.com/plus-circle-thin-svg/).